# Are browsers accept plugins today or just extension?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, plugins

I don't want to create extension because they are limited.
I would like my code to execute on any page from the browser.
I have read that creating plugin is deprecated for security reason (NPAPI).
There is Emscripten that looks like executed only on server.

Is there a way to code and execute program from the computer to access and modify browser page content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look TamperMonkey extension. That extension provide user made scripts and run.

[Chome Web Store Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)

Comment: Well, it does not allow me to code native (C/C++), but it looks like cross platform. No need to write manifest. It's ok. Thanks

Comment: if you have a local http server, you can write a script against your localhost http server and there you can do whatever you like.